# Exclude "this" cell from sum_range in SUMIF formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table

[image]

and am using the following formula to sum a range per month using sumif in Google Sheets

```
=sumif($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C)
```

I would like the total value to be displayed in column C, which is the range I am summing.

I would like the total to be display in the same column as the sub entries. How do I exclude the cell containing the total value so the formula doesn't become self-referencing?

Comment: Fundamentally you cannot do this on a dynamic basis. You'd have to specify the ranges outside of the summation (as the answer below describes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total is in cell C1, then:

```
=sumif($B2:$B2000,$B1,$C2:$C2000)
```

Or you could name the ranges:

sales = $B2:$B2000

prices = $C2:$C2000

then:

```
=sumif(sales,$B1,prices)
```

Edit: As per the comment from pgSystemTester, Googlesheets allows the following construction:

```
=sumif($B2:$B,$B1,$C2:$C)
```

Comment: Google sheets offers the convenience of "half-column" references (not sure what the official term is but Excel should learn it!).  So I'd modify your formula to be `=sumif($B2:$B,$B1,$C2:$C)` for a more dynamic result.

Comment: @pgSystemTester wish that would work in excel... But will borrow your suggestion unless you want to add as an answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of an example table. I would basically like to sum per month and still show the total in the same column as the entries

Comment: @SolarMike, no thanks, Your answer is good. Just sign my petition to Microsoft to add this (once I start it...)